# Issue with data refreshing in Google Sheets

Tags: java, google-sheets

I created a Google Sheet to extract the viewer count of videos on Instagram using the following formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("URL"/?hl=en?update=1618016662170","//script[@type='application/ld+json']"),"userInteractionCount"":""(\d+)")
```

It's finicky, and occasionally has issues scraping the data properly, but overall it's been working okay. I then used the following two functions in order to have every instance of the formula update automatically every minute:

```
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("refreshGroupD")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create()
}
```

```
function refreshGroupC() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  if (!lock.tryLock(5000)) return; 

  var id = "ID";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var formulas = dataRange.getFormulas();
  var content = "";
  var now = new Date();
  var time = now.getTime();
  var re = /.*[^a-z0-9]import(?:xml|data|feed|html|range)\(.*/gi;
  var re2 = /((\?|&)(update=[0-9]*))/gi;
  var re3 = /(",)/gi;

  for (var row = 0; row < formulas.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < formulas[0].length; col++) {
      content = formulas[row][col];
      if (content != "") {
        var match = content.search(re);
        if (match !== -1) {
          // import function is used in this cell
          var updatedContent = content.toString().replace(re2, "$2update=" +
            time);
          if (updatedContent == content) {
            // No querystring exists yet in url
            updatedContent = content.toString().replace(re3, "?update=" + time +
              "$1");
          }
          // Update url in formula with querystring param
          sheet.getRange(row + 1, col + 1).setFormula(updatedContent);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Done refresh; release the lock.
  lock.releaseLock();

  // Show last updated time on sheet somewhere
  sheet.getRange(32, 2).setValue("Refreshed at " +
    now.toLocaleTimeString())
}
```

My issue is that eventually, every single one of the cells gives an infinite "Error: Loading Data". Currently, I only have 16 cells that are filled with this formula, but I'll have close to 600 such cells over time. Is there any solution as to why my sheet eventually fails to refresh the data or possibly a cleaner solution that might not be so taxing on the file? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### Beware that Apps Script has [quota limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

This which means e.g. that you have a maximum `Triggers total runtime` per day - depending on your account.

If you have a consumer account the limit is 90 min/day - that is 3.75 s per script execution.

How long does each of your script execution take? If more than 3 s, you will be running into quota issues.

The solution would be either to

- execute the time-based trigger less frequent
- upgrade to a Google Workspace account that would give you a higher execution limit

**Another point to consider:**

A request to update formulas (`sheet.getRange(row + 1, col + 1).setFormula(updatedContent);`) can take a longer time to execute. You should not try to access the sheets contents while formula are being updated.